# Search Text with Linebreaks recursiv in a directory?

Tags: linux, grep

I Have many large logfiles which are looks like that:

```
DATETIME ["2015-03-03 21:52"]
SERVER [{json_with_$_SERVER-Output}]
GET ["GET_JSON","AAA"]
POST ["POST_JSON","BBB","TEST1"]

DATETIME ["2015-03-03 21:53"]
SERVER [{json_with_$_SERVER-Output}]
GET ["GET_JSON","CCC"]
POST ["POST_JSON","DDD","TEST2"]

DATETIME ["2015-03-03 21:54"]
SERVER [{json_with_$_SERVER-Output}]
GET ["GET_JSON","AAA"]
POST ["POST_JSON","BBB","TEST3"]

DATETIME ["2015-03-03 21:55"]
SERVER [{json_with_$_SERVER-Output}]
GET ["GET_JSON","AAA"]
POST ["POST_JSON","EEE","TEST4"]
```

I want to search about 2 keywords (between them are linebreaks). one specific word in the GET-Line and one specific word in the POST-Line.

i need something like:

```
grep "GET(.*)AAA(.*)POST(.*)BBB"
```

what im **searching** for: AAA (in GET-Line) && BBB (In POST-Line)

the expected **result**:

```
POST ["POST_JSON","BBB","TEST1"]

POST ["POST_JSON","BBB","TEST3"]
```

with which simple methods this is doable?

Comment: It not clear what you are asking for.  What have you tried to solve this.

Comment: i tried different kinds of grep and regex, but im not good in such things... see answer below for more detailed question

Comment: Did none of the posted answers work for you?

Comment: I think your answer was very close, but i cant use it.. i answered my issue myself.. see my last answer.. Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this with grep -P for Regular Expressions as i know it from PHP and particularly with -A to get the next n Lines. Then i filtered the result with "|" and grep -P again

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ find . -type f |
xargs gawk -v RS= 'match($0,/\nGET.*AAA.*\n(POST.*BBB.*)/,a){print a[1]}'
POST ["POST_JSON","BBB","TEST1"]
POST ["POST_JSON","BBB","TEST3"]
```

Add `-v ORS='\n\n'` if you really want a blank line between output lines.

Comment: that looks nice.. i will try it out tomorrow

Comment: unfortunately this dont work. please see updated example. thank you so much at all...

Comment: I just updated my answer to match your updated example.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is the command you are searching for

```
grep -rHn "GET.*KEYWORD_A" -A1 /path/to/files | grep "POST.*KEYWORD_B"
```

I would first grep for lines containing `KEYWORD_A` and append one line after the match since the POST comes after the GET in your logfiles. Then search for `KEYWORD_B`

```
-r greps recursively in a directory
-H prints the file name
-n prints the line number
```

Comment: I want to searching for "KEYWORD_A" && "KEYWORD_B". KEYWORD_X and KEYWORD_Y are statics everytime at the same place. i need something like grep "KEYWORD_X(.*)KEYWORD_A(.*)KEYWORD_Y(.*)KEYWORD_B" but only with the results of the line with KEYWORD_B

Comment: please edit your question and add an example of what is your expected output for the input in the question

Comment: somewhat unlikely but it would produce a false result if a file named `POST_KEYWORD_B` or similar existed and contained only a string matching the regexp `GET.*KEYWORD_A`.

Comment: good point since pigs can fly. It would also not work if the json will contain newlines.

Comment: yeah it was more of a warning about the general approach than this specific problem, I'd be shocked if there was really an issue in this case.